# В чем причина этой ошибке Constants may only evaluate to scalar values

Tags: php

Warning: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values

Warning: Illegal string offset 'Anderson'

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name'

Код:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8a7fee1106138c744face89f03cc9b13b4e29b0

Comment: причина в версии PHP

Comment: @АлексейШиманский смысле!?  использую  редактор sublime text и openserver, все раньше работало. Что мне сейчас тогда делать?как исправить?

Comment: в прямом смысле.. версия PHP другая нужна. неужели ты не изучал в какой версии что используется? ....................Не может раньше работать и внезапно перестать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем страницу с описанием новой функциональности **PHP версии 7**: http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php – и находим:

**Задание констант массивов с помощью define()**

> Можно задать константу типа array с помощью функции define(). В PHP
>   5.6, такие константы можно было задавать только с помощью const.

---

Именно поэтому **в версиях PHP < 7.0** этот код:

```php
define(
    'DOSSIER',
    [
        "Anderson" => ["name" => "Thomas", "born" => "1962-03-11"], 
        "Reeves"   => ["name" => "Keanu",  "born" => "1962-09-02"],
    ]
);
```

– вызовет такой ворнинг:

> Warning: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values

Comment: Как обновить php?просто все время юзал редактор sublime и openServer раньше как-то на костылях работало, подскажите как обновить пхп?или редактор?запутался уже

Comment: Задайте лучше новый вопрос: "Как обновить PHP на OpenServer" - я не пользуюсь OpenServer, поэтому не помогу здесь...

Comment: Скачайте новую версию или просмотрите документацию OpenServer, там есть возможность в Модулях выбрать какую версию PHP использовать.